# How to compute LST every 3rd day for 19 years (Earth Engine)

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, modis

I want to calculate LST for every 3rd day from 01-02-2000 to 31-12-1-2019, I don't Know how to do that.

Using MODIS/006/MOD11A1

```
var lst = lstImg.select('LST_Day_1km')
         .filter(ee.Filter.date('2000-01-01', '2019-12-31'))
         .map(function(image){return image.clip(table)})
        .sort('CLOUD COVERAGE',false)
         .filterBounds(table);
var lstVis = {
  min: 13000.0,
  max: 16500.0,
  palette: [
    '040274', '040281', '0502a3', '0502b8', '0502ce', '0502e6',
    '0602ff', '235cb1', '307ef3', '269db1', '30c8e2', '32d3ef',
    '3be285', '3ff38f', '86e26f', '3ae237', 'b5e22e', 'd6e21f',
    'fff705', 'ffd611', 'ffb613', 'ff8b13', 'ff6e08', 'ff500d',
    'ff0000', 'de0101', 'c21301', 'a71001', '911003'
  ],
};
//Map.setCenter(6.746, 46.529, 2);

Map.addLayer(lst,lstVis,'LST');

print(ui.Chart.image.series(lstt.select('LST_Day_1km'), table, ee.Reducer.mean(),30));
```

Comment: Third day from the year? From each month? Please specify. Also, can you share a link of your code so your piece of code is reproducible?

Comment: EVERY third day from 01-1-2000 to 31-12-2019(include month from jan - dec)

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/51afbe8f9b6a683faef6562251d036ca

Answer (score 3):

Something like the below? You need to decide how to combine multiple days of images into one, here I took the median value. You also have some 3-day intervals without any imagery that you need to filter out. This code relies on that `median()` returns a 0-band image when there are no images in the collection.

```
var table = ee.Geometry(Map.getBounds(true))
var startDate = ee.Date('2000-01-01')
var endDate = ee.Date('2020-01-01')

var lst = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD11A1')
  .select('LST_Day_1km')
  .filterBounds(table)

var days = endDate.difference(startDate, 'days')
var daysStep = 3
var timeSeries = ee.ImageCollection(
  ee.List.sequence(0, days.subtract(1), daysStep)
    .map(function (offsetDays) {
      var start = startDate.advance(offsetDays, 'days')
      var end = start.advance(daysStep, 'days')
      var composite = lst
        .filterDate(start, end)
        .median() // You need to decide how to combine the images
      return composite
        .set('system:time_start', start.millis())
        .set('empty', composite.bandNames().size().eq(0))
    })
  ).filterMetadata('empty', 'equals', 0)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/f75f7bcc1af63ce8e1b74872555168c9

You will probably run into trouble charting this by taking the mean at 30m scale.

Comment: i cant create map from above code ?

Comment: What kind of map did you have in mind? It's an ImageCollection, so the images can be shown on a map. This is the first image in the collection: https://code.earthengine.google.com/84374643b1fc407fa10d2acefd630c9d